# Rewrite rule not working, return 404 not found

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i configure the htaccess as shown below

```
// this htaccess in /var/www/html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog1/public/ [L]
RewriteRule ^market(.*)$ blog2/laravel/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

this is the htacess in blog2

    
        Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I moved my index.php from laravel folder to blog2.

when i access http://website.com/market it will always go to the blog1 rule, not redirect to blog2/laravel.

there will be fine if http://website.com/blog2, but the reason i want to do this because want to make the url in this way http://website.com/market-us etc.

What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching places for your two rewrite rules. Put `^market(.*)$` as the first one, and `^(.*)$ blog1/public/ [L]` right under it.

Comment: Will this causing any issue if switching it?